# Why is my PCollection (SCollection) size so larged compared to BigQuery Table input size?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, spotify-scio

[image]

The above image is the table schema for a big query table which is the input into an apache beam dataflow job that runs on spotify's scio. If you aren't familiar with scio it's a Scala wrapper around the Apache Beam Java SDK. In particular, a "SCollection wraps PCollection". My input table on BigQuery disk is 136 gigs, but upon looking at the size of my SCollection in the dataflow UI it is 504.91 GB. 
[image]

I understand that BigQuery is likely much better at data compression and representation, but a >3x increase in size seems quite high. To be very clear I'm using Type Safe Big Query Case Class (let's call it Clazz) representation, so my SCollection is of type SCollection[Clazz] instead of SCollection[TableRow]. TableRow is the native representation in the Java JDK. Any tips on how to keep the memory allocation down? It is related to a particular column type in my input: Bytes, Strings, Record, Floats, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely due to the TableRow format which contains string names for the columns, that add to the size.

Consider [using the following](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.java#L384) to create a PCollection of objects instead of TableRows. This allows you to directly read into an object which matches the schema, which should reduce the data size a little bit.

```
  /**
   * Reads from a BigQuery table or query and returns a {@link PCollection} with one element per
   * each row of the table or query result, parsed from the BigQuery AVRO format using the specified
   * function.
   *
   * <p>Each {@link SchemaAndRecord} contains a BigQuery {@link TableSchema} and a
   * {@link GenericRecord} representing the row, indexed by column name. Here is a
   * sample parse function that parses click events from a table.
   *
   * <pre>{@code
   * class ClickEvent { long userId; String url; ... }
   *
   * p.apply(BigQueryIO.read(new SerializableFunction<SchemaAndRecord, ClickEvent>() {
   *   public ClickEvent apply(SchemaAndRecord record) {
   *     GenericRecord r = record.getRecord();
   *     return new ClickEvent((Long) r.get("userId"), (String) r.get("url"));
   *   }
   * }).from("...");
   * }</pre>
   */
  public static <T> TypedRead<T> read(
      SerializableFunction<SchemaAndRecord, T> parseFn) {
```

Comment: I'm using a Type Safe Big Query Case Class which may just be scio's wrapper around a typed read not a TableRow

Comment: Internally, Dataflow uses a certain coder and tries encoding sampled elements of your PCollection to discern an estimated size.  Is it possible that this coder is producing output much larger than the actual size of a row?

Answer (score 0):

Case class serialization with Kryo is not most efficient since Kryo serializes the full class name of each object. You can work around this by registering the classes that go through expansive shuffles.

https://github.com/spotify/scio/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-use-custom-kryo-serializers

This will be addressed in Scio 0.7.x with the new Magnolia macro based coder derivation.

https://github.com/spotify/scio/wiki/Coders